# Deploying a shiny app on Google Cloud App Engine returns an Error

Tags: r, google-app-engine, shiny, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy a shiny app (without shiny server) on Google Cloud App Engine flexible environment. So I dockerised my shiny app and it works well on my computer.

Here is app.yaml :

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

Here is my docker file :

```
# start with the official R project base image
FROM r-base:latest

# copy this github repo into the Docker image and set as the working directory
COPY . /usr/local/src/myscripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/myscripts

# Install the C/C++ libraries needed to run the script
RUN apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
libssl-dev \
libcurl4-openssl-dev \
libxml2-dev

# Install the R libraries needed to run the scripts
RUN /usr/bin/R --vanilla -f install_libraries.R

EXPOSE 8080

# Execute the target script
CMD ["Rscript", "run.R"]
```

And here is my Rcode launching my shiny app :  run.R

```
library(shiny)
runApp(port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0",launch.browser = FALSE)
```

All the deploying goes well but when I go to my app engine -https://.appspot.com/ - I have this error in the console. And the application looks grey.

[image]

Is there a way to put my shiny app on an app engine and not on a compute engine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiny is based on WebSockets that were not supported by the App Engine at this time. They are however supported now ([link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-websockets-support-for-app-engine-flexible-environment)) out of the box in the Flexible environment. This makes a Shiny App very easy to Deploy on App engine. Essentially, your code should just work now.